# c# nullreferenceexception thrown when an object is not null

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

i have this snippet of code that is used to retrace the path found by the a* algorithm. for some reason i can't wrap my head around, it throws a nullreferenceexception:

```
void drawpath(GridLocation start, GridLocation end) {
    List<GridLocation> path = new List<GridLocation>();
    GridLocation current;
    current = end;

    while (current != start) {
        path.Add(current);
        current = current.parent;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(path.Count);
    path.Reverse();
    grid.path = path;
}
```

the error i'm getting is `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'current was null.`

following is the implementation for my GridLocation class:

```
public class GridLocation {
public bool isPassable;
public int gcost, hcost;
public int value, x, y;
public GridLocation parent;
public GridLocation(bool _isPassable, int _x, int _y, int _value) {
    isPassable = _isPassable; x = _x; y = _y;  value = _value;
}
//gets the total cost of the nodes based on the hcost and gcost variables
public int fcost {
    get {
        return (gcost + hcost);
    }
}
```

}

and the way i call the method:

```
 if (current.value == target.value) {
            drawpath(start, target);
            Console.WriteLine("Path found!!!");
            return;
 }
```

worth noting is that if i try checking if the objects are the same (like this `if (current == target)`) nothing happens

edit: i'm new to c#, and i already tried everything else, that's why i'm posting here.

Comment: On which line do you get the exception?

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace?

Comment: the line where this line of code is 'current = current.parent;'

Comment: @Bozgorian it seems that some `GridLocation` would not have parent.

Comment: Change `while (current != start)` to `while (current != start && current != null)`